# Access the html location of all elements from a database with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I display elements from a database with php and my goal is to change the style of the html tags that contain them, when hovering over them with javascript.
But the problem is that it works only for the first element displayed. As if the other elements didn't have the same tag class for javascript.

here is code html and php :

```
<div class="eventsContainers">
           <?php
           foreach($eventsInfo as $eventInfo)
           {
              if($eventInfo['pseudo_author'] == $_SESSION['pseudo'])
              {?>
                 <div class="event" align="center">
                    <div class="headerEvent">
                       <div class="ppEventContain">
                          <p><?php echo $eventInfo['title']; ?></p>
                       <div class="eventDateRegister">
                          <p><?php echo $eventInfo['paragraphe']; ?></p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Here is code css:

```
.eventsContainers
{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.event
{
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 10px;
   width: 50%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #848484;
   margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Here is code js:

```
const event = document.querySelector(".event");
event.addEventListener("mouseover", extendEvent)
function extendEvent()
{
  event.style.position = 'absolute';
  event.style.width = "28%";
}
```

here is the source code that it gives:

```
<div class="event" id="event1 align="center">...</div>
<div class="event" id="event2 align="center">...</div>
<div class="event" id="event3 align="center">...</div>
<div class="event" id="event4 align="center">...</div>
<div class="event" id="event6 align="center">...</div>
<div class="event" id="event7 align="center">...</div>
<div class="event" id="event8 align="center">...</div>
```

By doing an "event:hover" in the css only id="event1" will react to the event and will have a width = 28% and a position = absolute. With my method they all react to the hover except that again only 1 element has width = 28% and position = absolute. This time it is the last element, id="event8".

Of course it would be much easier if I could know the id of the elements but as the class element can be infinite then it's complicated.

Comment: [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): _"The Document method `querySelector()` **returns the first Element within the document that matches** the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned."_

Comment: You don't need JavaScript for this -> `:hover`

Comment: Thanks, it works with all the tags but the new problem is that it displays the same data (i.e. the 1st doone of the database) no matter which tag I went over.

Comment: For my understanding you don't need any JavaScript for a hover - effect. Like Andreas mentioned above or micahlt gave you an example in its answer below. But if you want to go the JavaScript way, then think about assigning a class (".event:hover") to your html element instead doing it within your JS code.

Comment: The problem is that with this method, only the first element of class "event" will react to the event. Since tags of class "event" can be infinite because they have been implemented in a loop.  I made some modifications to my question above

Comment: @VebDav you actually can't assign pseudo-classes like `:hover` with JavaScript.  If the OP insists on doing this with JavaScript (which they shouldn't) there would need to be another class (maybe `.hovered`) that would be added on hover via `querySelectorAll()` and adding event listeners to each element.  As stated below though, this is highly discouraged since it's built in to CSS.

Comment: @micahlt yes you are right. I didnt mean to assign a pseudo class with javascript. I get your point while I am re-reading my comment, it is missleading. But you did explain it way better than me.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing this is extremely convoluted and definitely not recommended.  Instead, please use the [CSS hover selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and change your styling directly with CSS.  This will also be much more performant than manually adjusting styles with JavaScript.  In your case, the stylesheet would look like this:

```css
.event {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #848484;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.event:hover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 28%;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that with this method, only the first element of class "event" will react to the event. Since tags of class "event" can be infinite because they have been implemented in a loop. 
I made some modifications to my question above.

Comment: That's not how CSS works - a single class selector targets *all* elements in that class.  If it's not working, then there's some other stylesheet that's counteracting your styles.

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework that might be inlining your styles during some sort of build step?  That's the only other possible explanation I can think of.